# How to set marker title from EditText

Tags: android, google-maps, android-edittext, google-maps-markers

I use this code..

```
@Override
public void onMapLongClick(final LatLng point) {
   LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);  // Get the layout inflater
   dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, null);
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
   builder.setTitle("New Marker");
   builder.setView(dialogView);      
   //Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
   editText_markerTitle = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editText_custom);
   //editText_markerTitle.requestFocus();
   markerTitle = editText_markerTitle.getText().toString();
   ..................so on
}
builder.show();
```

and drawMarker func as:

```
public void drawMarker(LatLng point){
marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
.title(editText_markerTitle.getText().toString())
.position(point));
}
```

The problem is that, when i run the app first it get title from the  editText_markerTitle  perfectley and shows title in infowindow. but when i again run the app. the app crashes. don't know what the problem.

Comment: post your app logcat here

Comment: You might be getting NPE..show your logcat please